# Display currency symbols using facebook sharer.php

Tags: php, facebook, currency, symbols

I have the folloiwng facebook `sharer.php` script running on a facebook page tab application. 
The share works great until I try and add a currency symbol using

```
htmlentities(money_format("%10.2n", $numrows[price]))
```

The funny thing is, this share option is on a page as well as the currecny symbol, and the currecny symbol is displaying correctly

here is the complete code.

```
<?php
    $title=urlencode(''.$numrows['title'].' | '. htmlentities(money_format("%10.2n", $numrows[price])).' '.$currency_code.'');
    $url=urlencode(''.$token.'');
    $summary=urlencode(''.$numrows['description'].'');
    $image=urlencode(''.$numrows['img1'].'');
?>
<a id="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=550,height=400');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
<input type='submit' class='btn' title='Share This Item With Friends' value='Share On Facebook'></form>  
</a>
```

Thanks in advance, this has been driving me crazy for a number of days now

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the symbol is one thing, but adding it to a query string is completely different.
I'm not sure what's the result of calling `htmlentities(money_format(...))` since I'm not a php programmer, but my guess is that you need to url encode it in order to add it into the querystring, just like with '=', '?' and '&'.

With that said, you should be aware that the facebook share is deprecated and no longer supported, as you can read in the docs:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

And:

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

You should switch the the like button, but there too you'll need to url encode things.